# Java gui blank space error checking

Tags: java, swing

got a bit of some error checking on a java swing gui that I am trying to complete for an assignment for class. 
The sections that need checked are where the user will input their digits for the qty of pizza and qty of soda before the calculations. What I want for the program to do, is to detect a blank space and provide a popup telling the user that the space is blank and requires a number from 0-100. 
I'm looking for it to do anything but crash or give exceptions. I'll worry about the text of the popup once we get the error checking figured out.
Any and all help is greatly appreciated.......

```
private void btnCalcActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    final double LOCAL_TAX = .02;
    final double STATE_TAX = .06;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    int intPizza = Integer.parseInt(qtyInputPizza.getText());
        while (!intPizza.hasNextInt(101))
            {

            }
    int intSoda = Integer.parseInt(qtyInputSoda.getText());

    double dblPizzaSub = intPizza * PIZZA_PRICE;
    double dblSodaSub = intSoda * SODA_PRICE;

    pizzaSubtotal.setText(nf.format(dblPizzaSub));
    sodaSubtotal.setText(nf.format(dblSodaSub));

    double dblNetSale = dblPizzaSub + dblSodaSub;
    netSaleValue.setText(nf.format(dblNetSale));

    double dblStateTax = dblNetSale * STATE_TAX;
    double dblLocalTax = dblNetSale * LOCAL_TAX;
    stateTaxValue.setText(nf.format(dblStateTax));
    localTaxValue.setText(nf.format(dblLocalTax));

    double dblTotalSale = dblNetSale + dblStateTax + dblLocalTax;
    totalSaleValue.setText(nf.format(dblTotalSale));

    btnClear.requestFocusInWindow();
}
```

Comment: are you looking for qtyInputPizza.getText().length() ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it is possible. I'm currently working with while (qtyInputPizza.equals("")) to see if I can get the program to detect a completely blank space. I currently have it set to when the person clicks clear or is initializing the program that it sets the two dialog boxes (labeled qtyInputPizza and qtyInputSoda) to 0 so that the program does not crash when calculate is pressed. If the boxes are blank where the user types the quantity in, or a letter presumably, the program crashes.

Comment: st.replaceAll("\\s+","") removes all whitespaces and non visible characters such as tab, \n

then you can check if it's int

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
int intPizza = Integer.parseInt(qtyInputPizza.getText());
```

by

```
String strPizza = qtyInputPizza.getText();
int intPizza = 0;
if ( strPizza == null || strPizza.trim().length() == 0 ) {
  // Display your error message
}
else
{
 // You can add a test to make sure it is an int not something else
 ntPizza = Integer.parseInt( strPizza  );
}
```

Comment: The trim method should be after the getText method.  That way, the parseInt method doesn't fail because of a space.

Comment: Ok, the blank space check is currently working. Thank you for that Stephane. I am, however, experiencing difficulty as to what approach to take to test for an integer. I've tried a while statement and it didn't work. What do I seem to be missing?

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working perfectly with a try catch statement since it always crashed with a numberformatexception. Thanks again for your help!